# Updating time function every second in NSDate() - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that gives me a time when the app is opened but I don't want it to be static I want it to be dynamic, updating every second. I thought of it being in a loop, but I don't know how to go about doing it. Doing a loop could work but if you have a better way of doing it please answer. Here is my function:

```
func timeNowString() -> NSString {
        let date = NSDate()

        var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
        outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let timeString = outputFormat.stringFromDate(date)
        return timeString;
    }
```

**Question:** How do I make this function dynamic? So it goes and updates every second instead of it being a static label.

If you have any questions please comment down below.

Comment: probably an NSTimer or something similar, perhaps with the date and formatting logic in a background thread (if it ends up being too intensive).

Comment: @MillieSmith I'm just trying to make a time display in real time would that work?

Comment: @Grapeapplesauce Yes, it would. Read the [official documentation of `NSTimer`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant How do I use NSTimer in my case

Comment: You read the official documentation, and then you use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.  You'll need to add a label and a button and hook them up to the textLabel and start IBAction.  You can modify this to add hours (just minutes/seconds here) and add a timer.invalidate() where you need it.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
        var timer = NSTimer()
        if !timer.valid {
            let selector : Selector = "countTime"
            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target:self, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        }
        let timeNow = timeNowString() as String
        for item in timeNow {
            time = timeNow.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
        }
    }

    var time = [String]()
    var startTime = NSTimeInterval()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func countTime() {
        var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
        var adjustedTime = Int(elapsedTime) + 3600*time[0].toInt()! + 60*time[1].toInt()! + time[0].toInt()!

        var hours = Int(Double(adjustedTime)/3600.0)
        let minutes = Int(Double(adjustedTime - hours*3600)/60.0)
        let seconds = adjustedTime - hours*3600 - minutes*60

        let startHours  = hours > 9 ? String(hours):"0" + String(hours)
        let startMinutes  = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
        let startSeconds  = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)

        timeLabel.text = "\(startHours):\(startMinutes):\(startSeconds)"
    }


    func timeNowString() -> NSString {
        let date = NSDate()
        var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
        outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let timeString = outputFormat.stringFromDate(date)
        return timeString;
    }
}
```

Comment: This just counts up from 0 how do you make it count up from the real time?

Comment: You have to get the real time and use the method I gave you to count up from there.  I assumed from your code you knew how to get the current time in a normal date format.

Comment: `func timeNowString() -> NSString {
        let date = NSDate()
        
        var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
        outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        let timeString = outputFormat.stringFromDate(date)
        return timeString;
    }` is the code for getting the real time, but how do I implement it in my code. Thank you, you have been such a great help on all my questions

Comment: Updated, give it a whirl.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63976/discussion-between-grapeapplesauce-and-steve-rosenberg).