# Updating a function that get the exact time - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a function that gets the exact time. This is the code:

```
func getTime() {
    var date = NSDate()
    var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
    outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    println(outputFormat.stringFromDate(date))
}


getTime()
```

It gets the exact time but does not update every second. I have a function that gets the exact time when the view loads, but it counts up just when the system can count up and the system can not keep up with the exact time, and it lags a couple seconds behind.

**What function will make this update every second in real time**

**Code for getting the time**

```
var time = [String]()
var startTime = NSTimeInterval()

//This is the viewDidLoad Function
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    handler(theDatePicker)
    var timer = NSTimer()
    if !timer.valid {
        let selector : Selector = "countTime"
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target:self, selector: selector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }
    let timeNow = timeNowString() as String
    for item in timeNow {
        time = timeNow.componentsSeparatedByString(":")
    }

    theDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("handler:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    func getTime() {
        var date = NSDate()
        var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
        outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
        outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        timeLabel.text = (outputFormat.stringFromDate(date))
    }






}


func countTime() {
    var currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime
    var adjustedTime = Int(elapsedTime) + 3600*time[0].toInt()! + 60*time[1].toInt()! + time[0].toInt()!

    var hours = Int(Double(adjustedTime)/3600.0)
    let minutes = Int(Double(adjustedTime - hours*3600)/60.0)
    let seconds = adjustedTime - hours*3600 - minutes*60

    let startHours  = hours > 9 ? String(hours):"0" + String(hours)
    let startMinutes  = minutes > 9 ? String(minutes):"0" + String(minutes)
    let startSeconds  = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)

    //timeLabel.text = "\(startHours):\(startMinutes):\(startSeconds)"
}


func timeNowString() -> NSString {
    let date = NSDate()
    var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
    outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    let timeString = outputFormat.stringFromDate(date)
    return timeString;
}
```

**viewDidAppear Function**

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        func getTime() {
            var date = NSDate()
            var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
            outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
            outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
            timeLabel.text = (outputFormat.stringFromDate(date))
        }

        let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "getTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        timeLabel.text = "\(timer)"
    }
```

Comment: Where is the difference to your previous question [Updating time function every second in NSDate() - Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26646285/updating-time-function-every-second-in-nsdate-swift) ???

Comment: @MartinR It counts up when the system is ready to, I need it to count up to the exact time

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand it. You cannot "update a function". What do you mean by "it counts up" and "when the system is ready to"?

Comment: I need a function that gets the exact time every second that shows the hours minutes and seconds

Comment: Did you start a timer to call this function regularly, as explained in the (accepted) answer to your previous question?

Comment: It seems that my comments caused some revenge downvoting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:
**You have your timer set for .01 seconds, not every 1 second.**

There is some other issue in your code if you are saying the system lags a few seconds when initializing NSDate() (aka, current time). Make sure your on the main thread. The code you have works fine so check where you're calling that function. If your getTime() function is called in viewDidAppear it will be exactly when the view appears and the time will reflect that. Set an NSTimer for the amount of time you'd wish for the refresh to occur and set the action to getTime()

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("getTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // This will call the getTime function every second which in turns updates your label
}

func getTime() {
    var date = NSDate()
    var outputFormat = NSDateFormatter()
    outputFormat.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier:"en_US")
    outputFormat.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    timeLabel.text = (outputFormat.stringFromDate(date))  // This line here will update your timeLabel with the current time every second
}
```

Comment: should it be in `viewDidLoad`? What is the main thread?

Comment: Where are you calling getTime()? From an NSTimer? Post more code please.

Comment: If you want it to be exactly when the view appears then call it from viewDidAppear().

Comment: Check my update function where it says the viewDidAppear function when I run the app it shows this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ns658q6dxu6ye72/Screenshot%202014-11-07%2009.40.05.png?dl=0

Comment: Do not put the getTime function inside your viewDidAppear function. The idea of the viewDidAppear function is to initialize the timer that will repeat every second starting when the view appears. The getTime() will get called every 1 second and will update your label. Move the getTime function outside of the viewDidAppear. I'll update my answer.